# CoderByte challenge - Letter Exchange

Tags: javascript

So I was doing some code challenge over on CoderByte and I can't get the Letter Exchange to work. The idea is to exchange all characters in a string with ones that are after them in alphabet. I tried with this code:

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 

var string = "";
var i = 1;
var alp = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var c = "";

for(i; i<=str.length; i++){
  c = alp.charAt(alp.indexOf(str.charAt(i)));
  string = string + c;
}

return string; 

}

LetterChanges(readline());
```

But it won't work and I'm not sure why. It would be very helpful if you could point out my mistakes. :)
I know this is easy problem for lot of you guys out there, but I'm new to JavaScript.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, your for loop needs some work. You should initialize `i` to `0`, the first index, since accessing letters from a string is zero-based. The length of a string, however, is one-based, so if you were to try to access the character at `str.length` it will return `null`.

Try this:

```js
function LetterChanges(str) {
  var string = "";
  var i = 0;
  var upper =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var c = "";

  for(i; i<str.length; i++){
    if(str.charCodeAt(i) == str[i].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)){ // check if it's uppercase
      c = upper[(upper.indexOf(str[i])+1)%upper.length]; // modulo for edge case if it's a zed
    } else { // otherwise it's lowercase
      c = lower[(lower.indexOf(str[i])+1)%lower.length]; // same thing as what's in the uppercase
    }
    string = string + c;
  }

  return string;
}
LetterChanges(readline());
```

Notice what I did, separating the upper and lower case letters. That's because I was assuming that you had to change the letter within the case. (so `Z` would become `A`, `z` would become `a`)